# Get input tag element with a given text value via xpath

Tags: xpath

How can I select, via xpath, all input elements in a document that have a given value typed into them.

For instance, if I go to Google and type in "hello world", how do I get all input tags that have "hello world" typed into them?

Playing around with things like below haven't paid off, since the value in the text field isn't really part of the document.

```
document.evaluate("//input[text() = 'hello world']", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue
```

Should be pretty simple, but I'm surprisingly stuck.

Comment: Are you actually trying to grab those values from a page after it loads and a user does some actions, or do you already have the xml document somewhere and you want to search it?

Comment: Please read "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)", "[mre]" and their linked pages. We need the smallest example of your input and your code, that duplicates the problem _in the question itself_ so we can write code around it.

Answer (score 27):

Your x-path expression should searching for inputs that have the **value** attribute with 'hello world'

This is because that's where the value gets put into, not the inner text of the element.

The actual html element would look like:

```
<input type='text' value='hello world' />
```

The XPATH expression should look like:

```
//input[@value = 'hello world']
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the value is changed. In other words, it selects the default value (`Element#defaultValue`) rather than the live value.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative without jQuery for getting the `input` which contains the target text is:

```
//input[contains(@value, 'hello world')]
```

This would find the input even if the user types `"hello world number 7"`

Answer (score 0):

This also seems to work:

```
//input[@type='text'][@value='hello world']
```